# Hiding load bearing support inside wall

Tags: structural, load-bearing

My master bedroom has a support column from a load bearing beam that sticks out a foot in the center of my bedroom. It was added because of an addition to the house. It’s been an eyesore so I’m looking to remove it. I hired an engineer coming tomorrow but I’d also love to get a second opinion.

The beam spans about 12 feet, the size is 11' 1/4" tall and 3 1/2" thick. The new span would be about 13-14 feet to get it inside both walls. I sent a picture to the engineer and it says it might not be possible because of the clearance of the ceiling. The roof slopes down to meet the exterior wall.

My goal is to hide the support columns flush into the wall.

I’d love to hear your advice, this is my master bedroom where I will spend most of my time.

[image: Ceiling Clearance]

[image: More Ceiling Clearance]

[image: Interior wall side of the beam]

[image: Exterior wall side of the beam]

Comment: Drywall it and paint it. Build a closet/armoire/bookcase next to it (or around it.) It's an eyesore because it's not finished, but there are plenty of ways to use (or vanish) a short projecting wall.

Comment: There was a closet and it looked awful. Just oddly placed imo. It’s two beams on both sides of the room. I exposed it for the engineer.

Comment: IMO, it will be a very expensive proposition to replace the original beam with a longer one to go into the walls, and possibly adding bearing points  in/under the floor to pick up the point loads

Comment: @user3630509  It's the next day, can you give us an update? **Really expensive:**  Have the steal beam extended by welding or bolting on more length and move the support beam inside existing wall. ***Acceptable****: build a built in bookcase around/over it.

Comment: Did the engineer ever show up?  What did he say?

Comment: @jay613 yeah 4 by 8 box header steel about $800 in material

Answer (score 0):

**Really expensive:**  Have the steal beam extended by welding or bolting on more length and move the support beam inside the existing wall.

**Realistic**: Drywall it over and use those to symbolically create separate spaces in one room (bed room with adjoining sitting space, etc).

**Acceptable**: build a built in bookcase around/over it. Or camoflage it with an artificial tree, or set a desk or other furniture next to it. Or mount a flatscreen TV on an arm so the screen is angled to that side of room.

**Unique**: build out an angled wall hiding the corner in a right triangle. And mount a tall mirror.

Interior design usually takes in the entire room and furniture arrangement. Good luck!

Comment: Define expensive, my engineer didn’t make it today so he couldn’t give me a quote.

Comment: Okay maybe not much more then if you had the support run all the way to the wall and not next to it. But now you will also have to pay even more to have it hidden. I'm no structural engineer but I would think they would now have to consider how much this affects the exterior wall? What is under / over this wall?